# Matching a char in a matrix on Ocaml

Tags: matrix, ocaml

I am making a game solver and while using a matrix in OCaml, I need to check whenever it's complete, with A's or V's, to do so I attempeted to see if there is a '.' in at least one of the cells because that symbolizes an empty cell. Here goes the code:

```
let is_solved m n =
  for i=0 to n do
    for j=0 to n do
      if(m.(i).(j)='.') then false
    done
  done;;
```

So my is_solved function has to return false when it finds a '.' at any position or true if it doesn't. But OCaml is giving me a:

```
Error: The variant type unit has no constructor false
```

I am new to OCaml but can someone tell me what I need to fix or even why is it giving me that error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that the value of any OCaml construct of the form `for ... done` is `()`, the single value of type `unit`. You can't give a value to the loop as you seem to be trying to do.

Your immediate problem is that when you use `if` without `else` in OCaml, the value of the expression has to be of type `unit`. This is necessary because the type has to be the same in both cases. However, it's not really worth fixing this due to the above problem.

If you want to use `for` loops to solve your problem, you'll need to use an imperative approach. That is, you'll need to keep a mutable value to hold what you want to return at the end.

(Since you're new to OCaml it might be useful to try coding this function in a more functional style just to see how it looks.)

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll try to make it more functional.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this function in a recursive way as Jeffrey has suggested, just to give you a starting kick, I will provide a general template letting you to fill the gaps:

```
let todo = failwith

(* [is_solved field m n] true if exists '.' in the [field], where
   [field] is a matrix of size [m] x [n] *)
let is_solved field m n = 
  let rec outer = function 
    | 0 -> todo "outer loop ends" 
    | m -> inner m n 
  and inner m = function
    | 0 -> todo "inner loop ends"
    | n -> todo "inner loop workload" in
  outer m
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try but with my own exceptions instead of failwith. But your template will be very usefull.